# AWS Lambda - Unable to import module lambda-function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a simple Lambda function to connect and execute an Aurora MySQL DB operation.

The name of the function is `LogStream` and the Python file is `lambda_function.py` in which I have my `handler function`.

I have updated the handler from CLI and it was successful:

```
{
"FunctionName": "LogStream",
"FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:function:LogStream",
"Runtime": "python3.6",
"Role": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/LambdaRole",
"Handler": "lambda_function.handler",
"CodeSize": 777,
"Description": "",
"Timeout": 3,
"MemorySize": 128,
"LastModified": "2020-10-14T16:26:20.733+0000",
"CodeSha256": "gEM+bUDuBHBGiwPecUv+IT0QEBzR28Ave94F8hc=",
"Version": "$LATEST",
"TracingConfig": {
    "Mode": "PassThrough"
},
"RevisionId": "7403730c-5349-4766-a11f-c68d66420a4a",
"Layers": [
    {
        "Arn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxx:layer:pymysql:1",
        "CodeSize": 1621906
    }
],
"State": "Active",
"LastUpdateStatus": "Successful"
}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import sys
import logging
import rds_config
import pymysql
#rds settings
rds_host  = "aurora-mysql-instance-1.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
name = "admin"
password = "xxxxxx"
db_name = "Test"

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")
    logger.error(e)
    sys.exit()

logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS MySQL instance succeeded")
def handler(event, context):
    """
    This function fetches content from MySQL RDS instance
    """

    item_count = 0

    with conn.cursor() as cur:


cur.execute("create table Employee ( EmpID  int NOT NULL, Name varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (EmpID))")
    cur.execute('insert into Employee (EmpID, Name) values(1, "Joe")')
    cur.execute('insert into Employee (EmpID, Name) values(2, "Bob")')
    cur.execute('insert into Employee (EmpID, Name) values(3, "Mary")')
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("select * from Employee")
    for row in cur:
        item_count += 1
        logger.info(row)
        #print(row)
conn.commit()

return "Added %d items from RDS MySQL table" %(item_count)
```

I have added a `Layer` which has the `pymysql` dependency.

I cannot figure why it is failing with the error upon invocation:

`{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"}`

Comment: Try changing the function name from `handler` to `lambda_function`

Comment: @jellycsc still the same error

Comment: Can you show more detail for this error? Usually, this is caused by a bad import or some indent error.

Comment: one of dependancies package is missing in your lambda package or layer. check CloudWatch log for more details. If your log is not coming then give access to role to write CloudWatch log.